# Dynamic Sender profile display name

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am creating a dynamic sender profile retrieving info from a content area with ampscript. The current code is based on values within salesforce.

The current content is working although when I add additional parameters for language I am receiving errors the code which is receiving errors is:

```
%%[
Var @n, @EN, @FR
SET @EN = "English xxx"
SET @FR = "French yyy"
SET @n = Lookup("ENT.Salesforce_User_Data", "Name", "id", LongSFID([Relationship Owner SFID]))
]%%

%%[ IF region == "Atlantic" OR region == "Ontario" OR region == "Quebec" OR region == "Western Canada" OR region == "Institutional" THEN ]%%
    %%=v(@n)=%%
%%[ ELSEIF region == "" OR region == "Default" OR region == "Discount" OR region == "Other " AND (language != "French") THEN ]%% 
    %%= v(@EN) =%% 
%%[ ELSE ]%%
   %%= v(@FR) =%%
%%[ ENDIF ]%%
```

When testing the display name which should be French yyy is English xxx although when replying the correct name is displayed.

Comment: I'm not seeing an error message in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing a pair of parentheses in the `elseif`.

Also, I'd utilize the [**AttributeValue()**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/attributevalue/) function to ensure that the `language`, `region` and `Relationship Owner SFID` attributes are defined.

You can use the [**output()**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/output/) function to keep from having to open and close AMPScript blocks

```
%%[

var @n, @EN, @FR, @region, @ownerSFID, @language

set @n = Lookup("ENT.Salesforce_User_Data", "Name", "id", LongSFID(@ownerSFID))
set @EN = "English xxx"
set @FR = "French yyy"
set @region = AttributeValue("region")
set @ownerSFID = AttributeValue("Relationship Owner SFID")
set @language = AttributeValue("language")

]%%

%%[

if @region == "Atlantic" OR @region == "Ontario" OR @region == "Quebec" OR @region == "Western Canada" OR @region == "Institutional" then

  output(concat(@n))

elseif (empty(@region) OR @region == "Default" OR @region == "Discount" OR @region == "Other") and @language != "French" then

  output(concat(@en))

else

  output(concat(@fr))

endif

]%%
```

Comment: I figured out the issue it was not my coding although its not as clean as yours. The issue was the email address stated as a variable for the content area which I use to for the From Email of Sender.